# Is it possible to dynamically inherit from a class that is only known at runtime in python?

Tags: python, class, inheritance, closures

I want to expand the class `Foo` by the class `Bar`, the issue that I have is that I can't expand it in the usual way (`class Foo(Bar)`) because the class `Bar` is somewhat dynamically generated.

I made this small example to illustrate my desired outcome:

```
class Bar:
    def super_cool_function():
        print("Cool")

class Foo:
    def __init__(self, another_class):
        # I want to extend Foo by another_class

# Desired result
foobar = Foo(Bar)
foobar.super_cool_function()
```

Again this is ***not*** what I'm looking for:

```
class Foo(Bar):
    pass

foobar = Foo()
foobar.super_cool_function()
```

Comment: At what point is `Bar` known?  `class Foo(X):` works just fine even if `X` is a variable, not the literal name of the parent class.

Comment: I should point out that, in order for `super_cool_function` to be callable by an instance of Foo, it'd need the `self` parameter (`def super_cool_function(self):`). I'm not going to edit your question to correct it, because that would invalidate abarnert's answer.

Comment: You can also consider the strategy pattern: https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/strategy/python/1

Answer (score 25, accepted):

#### TL;DR: Yes, using python closures

"The class `Bar` is somewhat dynamically generated" That's fine... as long as it follows the blueprint (of a class that should be extended by `Foo`), you can leverage python closures here. Dynamically create a new class by creating it inside, and returning it from a function.

```
def get_class(superclass):
    class Foo(superclass):
        def __init__(self, ...):
           ...

    return Foo

DynamicFoo = get_class(Bar)
myobj = DynamicFoo()
```

This is a common pattern you'll see in python - leveraging closures to dynamically create callbacks and classes.

---

The answer above assumes that `Bar` is correctly defined, when it in fact is not. The `super_cool_function` is missing a self parameter. Instance methods are always called with the first parameter (the instance itself) automatically being passed in as the first attribute.

So, the correct definition for `Bar` would be:

```
class Bar:
   def super_cool_function(self):
       print("Cool")
```

Now, defining `get_class` with the simplest definition of the inner class `Foo`:

```
def get_class(superclass):
    class Foo(superclass):
        pass

    return Foo

DynamicFoo = get_class(Bar)
myobj = DynamicFoo()
myobj.super_cool_function()
# Cool
```

Answer (score 4):

Your desired use is a little strange:

```
foobar = Foo(Bar)
```

You're constructing a `Foo` instance by handing it the `Bar` class object, and expecting to get back something that acts like a `Bar` instance. Normally, a proxy class is designed to take an object to proxy to, or look on up somewhere, not just construct one with no arguments.

But, other than that oddness, which just means an `__init__` method that constructs the object, this is just a bog-standard proxy class. So:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, cls):
        self._inst = cls()
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return getattr(self._inst, name)
    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        if name in {'_inst'}:
            super().__setattr__(name, value)
        else:
            setattr(self._inst, name, value)
    def __delattr__(self, name):
        delattr(self._inst, name)
```

---

Of course you still won't be able to call that `super_cool_function` on a `foobar` any more than you could on a `Bar` instance, because it's defined as a method and doesn't have a `self` parameter. But you'll get the same error from the `Foo` instance that you would have gotten from a `Bar` instance:

```
>>> foobar.super_cool_function
<bound method Bar.super_cool_function of <__main__.Bar object at 0x129f95080>>
>>> foobar.super_cool_function()
TypeError: super_cool_function() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was
```

Comment: Any reason why you used `object.__setattr__` instead of `super().__setattr__`?

Comment: @Aran-Fey Probably just habit left over from Guido's original Python 2.2 examples or something, and I can't see any good reason not to use `super`, so… edited.